# Excel VBA Index/Lookup

Tags: excel, vba

```
  Dim worksheet1 As Worksheet
  Set worksheet1 = ActiveSheet

  Dim workbook2 As Workbook
  Set workbook2 = Workbooks.Open(("F:\Project Sweep\Kim Checklist\" & worksheet1.Cells(19, 12) & "\Consumers.xlsx"))

  Dim targetString As String
  targetString = "index('" & workbook2.Path & "\[" & workbook2.Name & "]Time'!$A$1:$E$366, 1, 1)"

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To 4
    worksheet1.Cells(7 + (i * 2), 7) = Application.Calculate(targetString)
Next i
```

The code is attempting to do the following:

- From worksheet 1, where the function is supposed to be called, it is supposed to pull from the worksheet Time in workbook 2, the value located at cell A1 (to be updated later to be iterative when the code is working), and place it in cell(7,7), cell(9, 7), cell(11, 7) and so on.
- The above code is giving the error "Compile Error: wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

The other option I was using was

```
 worksheet1.Range(Cells(7 + (i * 2), 7)).Formula = "=" & targetString
```

literally just placing the formula in the cell. But that gives the error "Run time error 1004: method range of object failed"

Any help would be appreciated thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Application.Evaluate, not Application.Calculate.

```
For i = 0 To 4
    worksheet1.Cells(7 + (i * 2), 7) = Application.Evaluate(targetString)
Next i
```

I'm a little unclear on what is going to change during that loop since the string that looks like a formula is static throughout.

Use .Address with External:=True to resolve a complete external path, workbook, worksheet and range.

```
with workbook2.worksheets("Time").range("A1:E366")
    targetString = "index(" & .address(external:=true) & ", 1, 1)"
    debug.print targetString
end with
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Check my recent addendum for a better way of creating the range address.